# Read_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission Target sdk 29

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

Ask Permission, Am Asking for permission in My simple music app to read external Storage

 It Asks for permission but doesn't list the Songs in the `ListView`

 minSdkVersion 27

 targetSdkVersion 29

It Shows the list of song after i terminate the app and start it again.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private  int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
ListView lvMusic;
MediaPlayer mp;
String name[],path[];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lvMusic = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMusic);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,null,null,null);

    name = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    path = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        name[i] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
        path[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name);


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestStoragePermission();

    }
   
    lvMusic.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

private void requestStoragePermission(){
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission Needed")
                .setMessage("This Permission is needed to Read Files")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                 .create().show();
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE ){
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission not Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function loadSongs() and call it when the permission is granted.

```
void loadSongs(){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,null,null,null);
    name = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    path = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        name[i] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
        path[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
        i++;
    }
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name);
    lvMusic.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
)
```

Now in your on create, check if the permission is granted or not,  if granted call loadSongs()

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    requestStoragePermission();
else
 loadSongs();
```

Now in onRequestPermission results call loadSongs if permission is granted:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE ){
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            loadSongs();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission not Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It Fixed my Issues, But can You Explain me why the earlier code wasn't working and what were problems, It would be  a big help! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya There were no issues. You were reading the songs before checking the permission read. So if the permission is not granted, songs will not be loaded and then you are asking for permission. So once the permission is granted it will just display the toast, So to see songs you have to restart the app.

Comment: Thank You! I have understood what i was doing, Thanks for your time!